# What's the exact definition of the power spectral density function?

Tags: power-spectral-density, autocorrelation, covariance

I learned from my signal processing course that PSD is the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function.

$$\mathscr{F}\Big\{\mathrm{E}\big[x(t)x(t+\tau)\big]\Big\}$$

Today I took my statistic course but my professor introduced spectral density function, which is the fourier transform of autocovariance function.

$$\mathscr{F}\Big\{ \mathrm{E}\left[\ \left( x(t)-\mathrm{E}\big[x(t)\big] \right)\left( x(t+\tau)-\mathrm{E}\big[x(t+\tau)\big]\right) \ \right] \Big\}$$

What is the exact definition of PSD?

If it's the FT of autocorrelation, then what's the name for the FT of the autocovariance function?

Comment: Hello, both can be correct and the definition depends on the context, the field, and the information you want to extract from the signal. Check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1625184/422470).

Comment: @AlexTP Thanks！

Comment: I think, because $x(t)$ is usually considered stationary, you need to expect that $$\mathrm{E}\big[x(t+\tau)\big]=\mathrm{E}\big[x(t)\big]$$
and all other expectation values are independent of any translation in time by $\tau$ or any other offset.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the terms *autocorrelation* and *autocovariance* are sometimes used to mean different things. In statistics, they often use *autocorrelation* for what would be called *autocovariance* in the signal processing literature (cf. [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/447275/231741) over at stats.SP).

The power spectrum is the Fourier transform of what in the signal processing literature is called *autocorrelation* function:

$$S_x(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}R_x(\tau)e^{-j\omega\tau}d\tau$$

with

$$R_x(\tau)=E\big\{x(t)x(t+\tau)\big\}$$

where I've assumed that $x(t)$ is a wide-sense stationary (WSS) random process.

The Fourier transform of the autocovariance

$$C_x(\tau)=E\big\{[x(t)-\mu_x][x(t+\tau)-\mu_x]\big\}=R_x(\tau)-\mu_x^2$$

is sometimes used for processes with a non-zero mean $\mu_x$ to avoid the Dirac delta impulse in the power spectrum at $\omega=0$. The Fourier transform of the autocovariance is called the *covariance spectrum* of $x(t)$.